# center float left for QuickSearch

Tags: html, css

I would like to center div for QuickSearch with several Q & A but no luck. The div is float left with background image.

**HTML**

```
<div class="l-row">
  <div class="QuickSearch">
    <div class="loop"></div>
    <form action=><div class="quickSearchInputName">xxx</div></form> 
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.QuickSearch {
  background: url(/templates/_system/main/images/job-search-bg.jpg) no-repeat top left;
  float:left;
  width:900px;
  height:170px;
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}

.loop {
  /* background: url(quickSearch.png) no-repeat;*/
  width: 10px; height: 135px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 0 2px;    
}

l-row {
  max-width:942px;
  width:100%;
  min-width:942px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.l-row`, btw?

Comment: When you say "center div" could you clarify what you want centred, and with respect to what else?

Comment: A float left is the antithesis of a margin: auto div. Not sure if you are confused about float or just not understanding what you need.

Comment: Hello, what is a purpose of that `.l-row` div? And why it's so complicated? More simple: `.l-row { width:942px; text-align:center; }`

Comment: @Stano: Changed .l-row but still not center.

Comment: If you want to have center the div.loop inside the div.QuickSearch, just use `.QuickSearch .loop { margin:0 auto;}` and don't make it float - http://jsfiddle.net/ft2Ja/3/ ,there should be no problem.

Comment: @Stano, thank you. .QuickSearch .loop { margin:0 auto;} .loop {float: left;} to make search form text inside the background image.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have an element with fixed size here, so I suppose you should follow the classic:

```
.loop {
  width: 10px; height: 135px;
  ...
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -67px;
  /* taking into account that margin-right: 2px in the original ruleset */
  margin-left: -3px; 
}
```

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ft2Ja/2/) (had to alter it somewhat, using plain colors instead of images for  backgrounds).

Comment: I would like background image: job-search-bg.jpg to be center. Sorry for making you all confused. After putting '.' infront of l-row also same. I did read some Q&A and all told about margin:0 to center float:left, if not mistaken...